# How to properly see files on raid mount?

Tags: data-recovery, raid, external-hdd

Operating System: PopOS (Ubuntu)

I have two external harddrives in a single case that were setup with a RAID1 configuration.

Had to get a new computer and after plugging in the external, the RAID partition shows up but appears to contain no data.

I'm curious to see if the data is actually gone (did I mess something up plugging into a new computer?) or is something wrong with the filesystem that is preventing me from seeing the files?

**My goal: Access the files on the harddrives**

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Have several hundred gb of photos on here I'd prefer not to lose...

Some terminal outputs below after plugging in the external...

[image]